# Cannot set express.static from another module

Tags: node.js, express

This works

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var request = require('request');

// initialize session, redis server will be used if it's running otherwise will store in memory
require('./config/session.js')(app, function () {
    // configurations
    require('./config/bodyparser.js')(app);
    require('./config/cookieparser.js')(app);
    require('./config/compression.js')(app);
    //require('./config/other.js')(app, express);
    app.use(express.static('./public', { /*maxAge: 86400000*/}));

    app.listen(3000, function () { console.log('running...'); });
});
```

But if I uncomment require other.js and comment app.use it doesn't. Here is the other.js file.

```
module.exports = function (app, express)
{
    app.use(express.static('../public', { /*maxAge: 86400000*/}));

    return app;
}
```

Tried different relatives paths but all failed. Here is the project structure

```
-config
--other.js
-public
-app.js
```

The error I get is

`Cannot GET /index.html`

on my browser, no error in console.

Comment: Any error message? What do you mean exactly by "it doesn't work", please?

Comment: you right I will edit my question

Comment: If you update other.js to use `./public` as the static folder does it work?

Comment: @SlashmanX yes it works, I tried all things like `./../public`, `.././public` but didn't try leave it as it is :) give an answer below and I will accept it. Actually it makes sense now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that when you `require` the other.js file, the relative path is using the cwd of `app.js`. The best way to avoid this (and avoid the hassle with relative paths) is to use `path.resolve` and the `__dirname` variable.

`__dirname` is a special Node.js variable that always equals the current working directory of the file it's in. So combined with `path.resolve` you can always be sure that no matter where the file is being `require`'d it uses the correct path.

In other.js:

```
var path = require('path');
....
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../public')));
```

Or you could simply update other.js to use `./public` but I believe the above is better practice as if you move the `app.js` or `require` other.js in a different folder it won't resolve correctly

Info on `path.resolve` [here](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_from_to)